# Strange operator overloading behavior?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Foo{

        string _s;
        public:
        Foo(string ss){
                _s = ss;
        }
        Foo& operator=(bool b){
                cout << "bool" << endl;
                return *this;
        }
        Foo& operator=(const string& ss){
                cout << "another one" << endl;
                return *this;
        }
};


int main(){

        Foo f("bar");
        f = "this";
        return 0;

}
```

I have overloaded `=` operator. I expected `f = "this";` statement to call `operator=(const string& ss)` overload. But it does not. It calls `operator=(bool b)` overload. Why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This operator `operator=(const string& ss)` requires a conversion of a user defined type for the argument (`const char*` to `std::string`), whereas the `bool` version has none and so provides a better match: you get the conversions from built-in types `const char[5]` to `const char*` to `bool`.

Comment: What?  There's only one UDT in that overload.  (Other than that, 100% correct)

Comment: @MooingDuck Yeah, you are right. It made sense when I typed the answer without thinking!

Comment: +1: It may surprise newcomers to the language that a type defined by The Standard would be classified as a **user**-defined type, but there you go!

Answer (score 1):

As noted by another answer, the pointer-to-char to `bool` conversion is preferred because it involves no user-defined conversions, while the `std::string` conversion has a user-defined conversion in it.

C++11 offers the ability to do manual type control.

```
template<size_t n>
struct enumarated_enum {
private:
  enum empty {};
};

template<bool b, size_t n=0>
using EnableIf = typename std::enable_if< b, typename enumerated_enum<n>::empty >::type;

template<typename String, EnableIf< std::is_convertible< String, std::string >::value >... >
Foo& operator=(String&& s) {
  cout << "string overload" << "\n";
}

// either this:
template<typename Bool, EnableIf< !std::is_convertible< Bool, std::string >::value && std::is_convertible< Bool, bool >::value, 1 >... >
Foo& operator=(Bool&& b) {
  cout << "bool overload" << "\n";
}
// or this:
Foo& operator=(bool b) {
  cout << "bool overload" << "\n";
}
```

where we match a type *perfectly* if it can be converted to a `std::string`, and the template doesn't match if it cannot be converted to `std::string` and other overloads are looked at.

If you have many types you want to be able to support, you have to use long logical forms that describe which of the overloads you want to run, and make sure the others don't accept it (with the not construct above).  If you only have two types, the second type can be a traditional overload.  The template overload gets first crack at anything that doesn't match the traditional overload exactly...

(The second template argument is a variardic list of numbered `enum`s which cannot exist, whose only purpose is to make sure that the two templates differ in sufficient ways for the compiler not to complain.)

Answer (score 0):

Without delving into C++ standards, on the surface your problem is, you defined your assignment overload with string& and a bool but in your test you're assigning a char* array.

So if you define a string and assign, it will work as expected.

Check it working here : http://codepad.org/owb6noXR

Comment: An alternative solution which removes the responsibility from the caller is here: http://liveworkspace.org/code/6UxaG$1 but this doesn't really answer the question of ***why*** that particular overload is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, an easy fix to this is to simply cast your string to an `std::string`, when doing the operator, so C++ knows exactly which overload to choose:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Foo{

        string _s;
        public:
        Foo(string ss){
                _s = ss;
        }
        Foo& operator=(bool b){
                cout << "bool" << endl;
                return *this;
        }
        Foo& operator=(const string& ss){
                cout << "another one" << endl;
                return *this;
        }
};


int main(){

        Foo f((string)"bar");
        f = (string)"this";
        return 0;

}
```

Comment: As I commented on another answer, an alternative solution which removes the responsibility from the caller is [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/6UxaG$1) but this doesn't really answer the question of ***why*** that particular overload is invoked.